# Can I set up a pen name for my story on WattPad?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing

I've written a story and want to make it available to readers on WattPad.

I want to use a pen name to hide my identity.

Is this possible on WattPad?

Comment: Are you registered on WattPad under your own name already?

Answer (score 1):

The stories on Wattpad are presented under your chosen user name for the account that you are using. There is nothing that enforces the use of a 'real' name. From experience, the majority of names do not appear to be 'real'.

It is also possible to set up more than one account though you need to use separate email addresses.